SQL to find missing records using NotExists
Wondering if anyone can assist with below SQL in Oracle. In my table, I have items setup at both WHs and DCs as 1-1 relations and my table looks like below.

I'm trying to write an SQL where I need to locate those items where the Item-Warehouse-DC record exists but a specific Item-DC relationship itself does not exist.
In below eg, Im trying to find Items that are missing setup with DC1 i.e. I'm trying to get Item5 and Item6

I tried with this but no luck.
select Item
from SKU
WHERE Warehouse in ('WH-A','WH-B','WH-C') 
and DC = 'DC1'
and not exists (select * from SKU where DC = 'DC1';

Thanks for any advice or input. My SQL is not very strong. thank you again.

I'm trying to understand what you mean. In your example, your table contains 20 records and for example Item1 appears twice. Once with column Warehouse=WH-A and column DC=DC-1. Once with column Warehouse=DC1 and column DC IS NULL. Is that correct?

Please edit your post to clarify what you're asking. You mention "Item-WH-DC" but that string nowhere appears in your graphic, nor does the string "Item-DC". This makes it hard for us to interpret what your rules are.

Hi Robert. yes that is correct. In the table, the items have a 1-1 relation with a WH and also with a DC and then the item-WH combination has a defined DC but Im trying to find items where a DC is defined for an item-WH-DC combo but the item-DC relation itself does not exist. Therefore in my eg, Im trying to find items not having a 1-1 with DC1 therefore Im looking for Item5 and Item6 as they are not setup 1-1 with DC1.

@redoctober I might be following. So for DC2 you'd want Item7 and 8?

Error2646...Yes that is correct if I were looking for DC2.

From what I understand, what you want is something like this.
select Item
from SKU s
WHERE Warehouse in ('WH-A','WH-B','WH-C') 
and DC = 'DC1'
and not exists (
    select 1
    from SKU 
    where Warehouse = s.DC and Item = s.Item
);


Hi Eric, yes this is exactly what i was looking for. thank you very much.

please clarify what you mean, it's quite hard to guess from your description.
SELECT s.Item
FROM SKU s
LEFT JOIN SKU s2 ON s2.Item = s.Item AND s2.Warehouse = s.DC
WHERE s.Warehouse IN ('WH-A','WH-B','WH-C') 
AND s.DC = 'DC1'
AND s2.Item IS NULL
;

As a result you will get
Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8

Thanks Kliment...Eric's SQL worked which is what i was trying to achieve. thanks for your input anyway.
